# Syntax error: Expecting token of type --> SLASH_OPEN <-- but found --> '' <--brs(1008)

Tags: xml, roku, brightscript

I'm new to XML. I'm doing the Roku App with BrightScript and XML.
On the top of my XML files, VSCode always warm me as 'Syntax error: Expecting token of type --> SLASH_OPEN <-- but found --> '' <--brs(1008)'. Does anyone know what is that means? THX!

Code is down below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Comment: It is a bug. Check it out here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/839866/please-vote-for-encoding-detection-from-xml-header.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using the [BrightScript Language](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RokuCommunity.brightscript) extension for vscode?

The error message is definitely a bit obscure, but it's caused by not having a `<component>` defined in your xml. Once you add a component tag, the error goes away.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I met the same error as a beginner in Roku development. After running the application in the debug mode, could I find the reason was that xml tags were not enclosed properly.

Please check more carefully, there would be a or more invalid xml tags like
**component** tag mentioned above in @TwitchBronBron's answer.

[image]